# How does relative path work for copy module of ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to clone a git repo in the ansible directory where the playbook will be executed from. Then copy files files from the cloned repo to a remote host.

Is this how I should specify the relative path? I don't want to use absolute paths.

```
- name: Clone a repository to localhost
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Clone repository
      git:
        repo: git@bitbucket.org:project1/repo1.git
        dest: ./repo1

- name: Copy files to remote hosts
  tasks:
    - name: Copy contents of bin directory
      copy:
        src: repo1/bin/
        dest: /home/root/bin/
```

For `src` does it have to be `./repo1/bin/` or `repo1/bin/` ? What about cloning to destination localhost. I currently I have `dest: ./repo1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference between  `./repo1/bin/` and `repo1/bin/`. In both cases, Ansible will clone the repository to *your current working directory*. So if you ran `ansible-playbook` from the same directory as your playbook...

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml
```

...the repository would show up in your playbook directory. If your cwd was, say `/some/path` and you ran the playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook /another/path/playbook.yaml
```

Then the repository would be `/some/path/repo1`, because `/some/path` was your cwd when you ran the playbook.

That may be fine for what you're doing. If you *explicitly* want the repository to be cloned into the playbook directory, then you can write:

```
- name: Clone repository
  git:
    repo: git@bitbucket.org:project1/repo1.git
    dest: "{{playbook_dir}}/repo1"
```

(But note the description of `playbook_dir` in [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#magic-variables).)

Comment: Once I clone the repo into playbook directory using `dest: "{{playbook_dir}}/repo1"`, for the copy tasks, I can use `repo1/bin/` right? That would be relative to the current directory where I ran playbook from.

Comment: The `copy` tasks will also look for relative paths in your current working directory. So if you need `{{playbook_dir}}` on your `git` task, you'll need it on the `src` of your `copy` task as well (or, alternately, if you're running ansible from the same directory as your playbook, just drop it in both cases).